# How can I search across all pages on my website

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have a search plugin that is more like a filter within a page (it's Swiftfilter and isotope filter). But I want the search to include all the pages on my website.

For example :
I am doing a travel website. When people search on index.html for "Italy". I want the search result directly link to italy.html page.

How can I do that? 
What does this call? 
Where can I learn/get this plugin?
Can swiftfilter or isotope filter enhance this?

Comment: So, you're going to create a static page for every country?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can get a bit complicated. I'm afraid it's not a simple as finding a single plugin that can do this. It sounds to me like you have a static website, where content is stored across different, hard-coded pages. A static website can get complicated because number one, it would be slow/clunky to search hard-coded files on a website. Number two, you would have to deal with caching systems to speed it up.

If you want to implement a search feature, I suggest that you have a template-driven/database enabled website instead. Why don't you consider moving your site and all its pages over to something like Wordpress?

All your pages would get stored in a database and WP already has its own built-in search functionality. It works really well and I think you should consider it if you have a lot of pages on your website.